# Moving image with cursor (parent being transform/css rotated)

Tags: jquery, css-transforms

Experts,

I created an image(#hand) movement along with mouse cursor (when being inside a div). This part is working fine unless when there is a transform rotate to #handWrap div. The hand image position moves different on a rotated parent div. I know, we should do some sort of calculation before passing the e.pageX and e.pageY position directly to hand, but couldn't find a proper fix. Would appreciate if anyone could help.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="handWrap">
    <img id="hand" src="http://s30.postimg.org/s4f5oy9dd/hand.png"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
#handWrap {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left: 80px;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
    /* try uncommenting below, hand position not being accurate */
    /* transform: rotate(-10deg); */
    cursor:pointer;
}
#hand{
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#handWrap").on("mousemove",function(e){
    // I played with sin/cos/half-width etc, but doesn't worked
    $('#hand').css({'left':e.pageX-130,'top':e.pageY-44});
});
```

**JSfiddle demo here:**
In jsfiddle, try uncommenting the transform rotate in #handWrap, then run, we could see hand movement is not accurate with mouse cursor

http://jsfiddle.net/y4pfd7u2/4/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i've tried transform-origin property but didn't work, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, finally I figured it out. As per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428192/get-new-x-y-coordinates-of-a-point-in-a-rotated-image), you can find the coordinates of the point after rotation using the `rotate` function below. Here is the final working version of your problem (and also [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4pfd7u2/5/)):

```js
$("#handWrap").on("mousemove",function(e){
    // I played with sin/cos/half-width etc, but doesn't worked
    var point = rotate(e.pageX, e.pageY, 100, 150, 10);
    $('#hand').css({'left':point[0]-110,'top':point[1]-30});
});


function rotate(x, y, xm, ym, a) {
    var cos = Math.cos,
        sin = Math.sin,

        a = a * Math.PI / 180, // Convert to radians because that's what
                               // JavaScript likes

        // Subtract midpoints, so that midpoint is translated to origin
        // and add it in the end again
        xr = (x - xm) * cos(a) - (y - ym) * sin(a)   + xm,
        yr = (x - xm) * sin(a) + (y - ym) * cos(a)   + ym;

    return [xr, yr];
}
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
#handWrap {
 position:absolute;
 top:40px; left: 80px;
 width:200px; height:300px;
 overflow:hidden;
 border:1px solid red;
    /* try uncommenting below, hand position not being accurate */
 transform: rotate(-10deg);
    cursor:pointer;
}
#hand{
 position: absolute;
 transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="handWrap">
    <img id="hand" src="http://s30.postimg.org/s4f5oy9dd/hand.png"/>
</div>
```

If anything is not clear for you regarding the solution or the equations, please ask me.

Comment: Karlen, you made my day this worked! thanks for the explanations.