# How to get x,y coordinates of a text that has been rotated by an angle in PIL python?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I'm adding a text on an image at a position (x,y) and then drawing a rectangle around it (x,y,x+text_width,y+text_height). Now I'm rotating the image by an angle of 30. How can I get the new coordinates ?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('img.jpg')
textlayer = Image.new("RGBA", im.size, (0,0,0,0))
textdraw = ImageDraw.Draw(textlayer)
textsize = textdraw.textsize('Hello World', font='myfont.ttf')
textdraw.text((75,267), 'Hello World', font='myfont.ttf', fill=(255,255,255))
textlayer = textlayer.rotate(30)
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428192/get-new-x-y-coordinates-of-a-point-in-a-rotated-image) . But I'm not getting the point correctly. Can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong.

```
textpos = (75,267)
theta = 30
x0,y0 = 0,0
h = textsize[0] - textsize[1]
x,y = textpos[0], textpos[1]
xNew = (x-x0)*cos(theta) - (h-y-y0)*sin(theta) + x0
yNew = -(x-x0)*sin(theta) - (h-y-y0)*cos(theta) + (h-y0)
```

Comment: Could you include missing code?  For example, you refer to "textpos", but that variable is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `PIL`, the *rotation* happens about the center of the image. So considering your center of the image is given by:

```
cx = int(image_width / 2)
cy = int(image_height / 2)
```

a specified rotation angle:

```
theta = 30
```

and given coordinates `(px, py)`, The new coordinates can be obtained using the following equation:

```
rad = radians(theta)

new_px = cx + int(float(px-cx) * cos(rad) + float(py-cy) * sin(rad))
new_py = cy + int(-(float(px-cx) * sin(rad)) + float(py-cy) * cos(rad))
```

Please note that the angle must be specified in **radians**, not **degrees**.

This answer is inspired from [this](http://datagenetics.com/blog/august32013/index.html) following blog-post.